# With Ace engine unable to read mixed mode excel Columns

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, oledb

First of all I can get it work if i Save that particular column as Text in Excel file, but my current requirement  doesn't allow that

My Connection String : 
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFileLoc + ";Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"

already tried

- Giving IMEX=1;HDR=NO
- Changing Reg value to avoid TypeGuessing (Setting TypeGuessing to 0)

Anyone have a working solution ?

Comment: Excel is extremely difficult to work with. Can you save the source as CSV and import that?

Comment: It would work , i appreciate the effort . to import xcel to CSV i had to use excel introp which requires ms office to be installed in deployed server ( of my knowledge) . so i have used another Xcel reader . Works great it solved my mixedtype column issue . you can download it on this  [link](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/). by the way Thanks @KeithL